# A single splunk event contains same field value pair multiple times. How to fetch single occurrence?

Tags: splunk

`"Env=abc"` is the field/value pair that every single Splunk event contains multiple no. of times. How to fetch only one of them to display in the time chart?

Ex:

```
Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc Env=abc
```

**I want "abc" to be displayed only once in my graph.** However, I see my graph displaying like below:

`abc abc abc abc abc etc`.

Comment: There are few ways to do that.  How are you extracting the fields?

Comment: I am using "timechart count by Env"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `| timechart xxx by Env` command to get the desired calculation you want from the events, e.g. the event count, distinct hosts, etc.

You can also use `| dedup Env` to only return 1 result for each distinct value of Env and then do your `|timechart`, but it will be an arbitrary event with that value, so depends on the calculation you want to perform whether that will suit.

If you just want to show if there were any events for each Env over time, I would do `| timechart dc(Env) by Env`